# Not able to execute embedded Saltstack state using gitfs

Tags: salt-stack, gitfs

I am working with the "**gitfs**" feature of SaltStack in order to execute a state file.
The state file uses the "include" feature to embed other two state files from the repository.

My repository has the following hierarchy:

```
salt 
    - dir1
             - dir3 / init.sls
             - dir4 / init.sls
    - dir2
             - dir5 / init.sls
```

My master file is as below:

```
. . .
fileserver_backend:
  - git

gitfs_remotes:
  - https://username@bitbucket.org/path/to/repo.git
. . .
```

The  salt/dir1/dir3/init.sls contains the following:

```
include:
  - salt/dir2/dir5/init.sls
  - salt/dir1/dir4/init.sls
. . .
```

On restarting salt-master and then executing 
salt-run fileserver.file_list saltenv=base backend=git
shows me all the files from the repository.
But on running 
salt '' state.apply salt.dir1.dir3 -l debug
I am getting the following error:

```
[ERROR   ] Data passed to highstate outputter is not a valid highstate return: {'<minion-id>': ['Specified SLS salt/dir2/dir5/init.sls in saltenv base is not available on the salt master or through a configured fileserver', 'Specified SLS salt/dir1/dir4/init.sls in saltenv base is not available on the salt master or through a configured fileserver']}
```

My system configurations are as follows:

```
$ salt --versions-report

Salt Version:
           Salt: 2016.3.3

Dependency Versions:
           cffi: Not Installed
       cherrypy: 3.2.2
       dateutil: 1.5
          gitdb: 0.5.4
      gitpython: 0.3.2 RC1
          ioflo: Not Installed
         Jinja2: 2.7.2
        libgit2: Not Installed
        libnacl: Not Installed
       M2Crypto: Not Installed
           Mako: 0.9.1
   msgpack-pure: Not Installed
 msgpack-python: 0.3.0
   mysql-python: 1.2.3
      pycparser: Not Installed
       pycrypto: 2.6.1
         pygit2: Not Installed
         Python: 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
   python-gnupg: Not Installed
         PyYAML: 3.10
          PyZMQ: 14.0.1
           RAET: Not Installed
          smmap: 0.8.2
        timelib: Not Installed
        Tornado: 4.2.1
            ZMQ: 4.0.5

System Versions:
           dist: Ubuntu 14.04 trusty
        machine: x86_64
        release: 3.13.0-91-generic
         system: Linux
        version: Ubuntu 14.04 trusty
```

The repository gets cached into the "/var/cache/salt/master/gitfs/refs/base/salt" path on restarting salt-master.
But I found "dir2/dir5/init/sls" instead of "dir2/dir5/init.sls"

> **What could be the reason for this issue?**

Comment: Is the code for this repository sitting in the "master" branch? If not then this would explain why the salt-master can't find the sls files. By default the `gitfs_base` that the master uses is the master branch. To target a specific branch you'd need to change this option in the master config. Alternatively, you can set the base to `__env__` and then when running a salt command just specify `saltenv=your_branch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most likely in your `include` declaration. Salt's `include` module treats SLS files similar to Python modules. For example, you would reference a SLS file `foo/bar/baz.sls` as `foo.bar.baz`.

Also, the `init.sls` file receives special treatment and enables you to treat an entire directory as a module. For example, `foo.bar.baz` would include either `foo/bar/baz.sls` or `foo/bar/baz/init.sls` (depending on which of them actually exists).

In conclusion, your `include` statement should look like this:

```
include:
  - salt.dir2.dir5
  - salt.dir1.dir4
```

Comment: Thanks, Helmbert.
How should I access a file dir2/dir5/abc.conf? Should it be dir2.dir5.abc.conf